Asterisk in Docker Container
I try to dockerize my asterisk setup but ran into a problem.
The problem is: Twinkle registers successfully, however, initiating a call from twinkle does initially succeed, but after ~20 seconds, asterisk hangs up automatically.
The setup is: asterisk runs within a docker container, a SIP softphone (twinkle is my current choice) runs on a different hardware machine.
The docker host has address 1.2.3.4 , twinkle runs on host 9.8.7.6 .
asterisk within docker sees 172.17.0.2 as its host.
Looking at the SIP dialog between the dockerized asterisk and twinkle, it looks as if
asterisk received the INVITE, sends an OK, and twinkle responds with an ACK, but that ACK is thrown away by asterisk - probably because its request line is
ACK sip:172.17.0.2:5060 SIP/2.0
byt it should be
ACK sip:1.2.3.4:5060 SIP/2.0
Asterisk keeps sending the OK-responses for ~20 secs, then sends a BYE request - probably because it did not receive a proper ACK and runs into a timeout?
My pjsip.conf looks like
[transport-udp]
type = transport
protocol = udp
bind = 0.0.0.0:5060
local_net=172.17.0.0/24
external_media_address= 1.2.3.4
external_signaling_address=1.2.3.4:5060


[external_endpoint](!)
type = endpoint
context = external
allow = !all,g722,ulaw,opus
direct_media = no
trust_id_outbound = yes
device_state_busy_at = 1
dtmf_mode = rfc4733
transport = transport-udp
aors = external_aor

[external_aor]
type = aor

[auth-userpass](!)
type = auth
auth_type = userpass

[aor-single-reg](!)
type = aor
max_contacts = 1

[4101](external_endpoint)
auth = 4101
aors = 4101
callerid = client Test 1 <4101>

[4101](auth-userpass)
password = xxxxx
username = yyyyy

[4101](aor-single-reg)

This is a (shortened version of) the SIP dialog between twinkle and asterisk:
INVITE from twinkle:
INVITE sip:5101@1.2.3.4:5060 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 9.8.7.6:26616;rport;branch=z9hG4bKhlmimhbs
Max-Forwards: 70
To: <sip:5101@1.2.3.4:5060>
From: "4101" <sip:4101@1.2.3.4:5060>;tag=tdlyk
Call-ID: vkhfyswqqkrgwif@muspel
CSeq: 105 INVITE
Contact: <sip:4101@9.8.7.6:26616;transport=udp>
Content-Type: application/sdp
Allow: INVITE,ACK,BYE,CANCEL,OPTIONS,PRACK,REFER,NOTIFY,SUBSCRIBE,INFO,MESSAGE
Supported: replaces,norefersub,100rel
User-Agent: Twinkle/1.10.2
Content-Length: 311

v=0
o=twinkle 338365061 1239230146 IN IP4 9.8.7.6
...

UNAUTHORIZED response from asterisk:
SIP/2.0 401 Unauthorized
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 9.8.7.6:26616;rport=26616;received=9.8.7.6;branch=z9hG4bKhlmimhbs
...

ACK from twinkle:
ACK sip:5101@1.2.3.4:5060 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 9.8.7.6:26616;rport;branch=z9hG4bKhlmimhbs
Max-Forwards: 70
To: <sip:5101@1.2.3.4>;tag=z9hG4bKhlmimhbs
From: "4101" <sip:4101@1.2.3.4:5060>;tag=tdlyk
Call-ID: vkhfyswqqkrgwif@muspel
CSeq: 105 ACK
User-Agent: Twinkle/1.10.2
Content-Length: 0

And another INVITE with proper credentials from twinkle:
INVITE sip:5101@1.2.3.4:5060 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 9.8.7.6:26616;rport;branch=z9hG4bKggpocztx
Max-Forwards: 70
To: <sip:5101@1.2.3.4:5060>
From: "4101" <sip:4101@1.2.3.4:5060>;tag=tdlyk
Call-ID: vkhfyswqqkrgwif@muspel
CSeq: 106 INVITE
Contact: <sip:4101@9.8.7.6:26616;transport=udp>
Content-Type: application/sdp
Authorization: Digest username="haas",realm="asterisk",nonce="1725889939/93169cfbe78e9f64692d2ec2303c28c5",uri="sip:5101@1.2.3.4:5060",response="5b64abba7d5daeda6012142677f720d0",algorithm=MD5,cnonce="b4f9df7496",opaque="2195b9a00d3b9bf4",qop=auth,nc=00000001
Allow: INVITE,ACK,BYE,CANCEL,OPTIONS,PRACK,REFER,NOTIFY,SUBSCRIBE,INFO,MESSAGE
Supported: replaces,norefersub,100rel
User-Agent: Twinkle/1.10.2
Content-Length: 311

v=0
o=twinkle 338365061 1239230146 IN IP4 9.8.7.6
...

OK response from asterisk:
SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 9.8.7.6:26616;rport=26616;received=9.8.7.6;branch=z9hG4bKggpocztx
Call-ID: vkhfyswqqkrgwif@muspel
From: "4101" <sip:4101@1.2.3.4>;tag=tdlyk
To: <sip:5101@1.2.3.4>;tag=XW0DQlRBdLoZPHIZCCX84tkx9S27hQ0q
CSeq: 106 INVITE
Server: Asterisk PBX 20.5.2
Contact: <sip:172.17.0.2:5060>
Allow: OPTIONS, REGISTER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, PUBLISH, INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, UPDATE, PRACK, MESSAGE, REFER
Supported: 100rel, timer, replaces, norefersub
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Length:   240

v=0
o=- 338365061 1239230148 IN IP4 1.2.3.4
...

(From here, RTP starts to flow properly.)
ACK response from Twinkle (that one seems to be thrown away by asterisk):
ACK sip:172.17.0.2:5060 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 9.8.7.6:26616;rport;branch=z9hG4bKdeqlxcpj
Max-Forwards: 70
To: <sip:5101@1.2.3.4>;tag=XW0DQlRBdLoZPHIZCCX84tkx9S27hQ0q
From: "4101" <sip:4101@1.2.3.4:5060>;tag=tdlyk
Call-ID: vkhfyswqqkrgwif@muspel
CSeq: 106 ACK
Authorization: Digest username="haas",realm="asterisk",nonce="1725889939/93169cfbe78e9f64692d2ec2303c28c5",uri="sip:5101@1.2.3.4:5060",response="5b64abba7d5daeda6012142677f720d0",algorithm=MD5,cnonce="b4f9df7496",opaque="2195b9a00d3b9bf4",qop=auth,nc=00000001
User-Agent: Twinkle/1.10.2
Content-Length: 0

The 'OK' is repeated ~ 20secs by asterisk, then it sends a BYE to twinkle:
BYE sip:4101@9.8.7.6:26616;transport=udp SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 172.17.0.2:5060;rport;branch=z9hG4bKPjRGhC.RJibs.8QuQi8vyaVPfY4b4EHf.n
From: <sip:5101@1.2.3.4>;tag=XW0DQlRBdLoZPHIZCCX84tkx9S27hQ0q
To: "4101" <sip:4101@1.2.3.4>;tag=tdlyk
Call-ID: vkhfyswqqkrgwif@muspel
CSeq: 20933 BYE
Max-Forwards: 70
User-Agent: Asterisk PBX 20.5.2
Content-Length:  0

And twinkle duly responds with 'OK':
SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 172.17.0.2:5060;received=1.2.3.4;rport=23187;branch=z9hG4bKPjRGhC.RJibs.8QuQi8vyaVPfY4b4EHf.n
To: "4101" <sip:4101@1.2.3.4>;tag=tdlyk
From: <sip:5101@1.2.3.4>;tag=XW0DQlRBdLoZPHIZCCX84tkx9S27hQ0q
Call-ID: vkhfyswqqkrgwif@muspel
CSeq: 20933 BYE
Server: Twinkle/1.10.2
Content-Length: 0

I guess the problem is, that twinkle uses sip:172.17.0.2:5060 as URI in the second ACK request, instead of sip:5101@1.2.3.4:5060 SIP/2.0 , is this correct?
I guess further, that this is due to asterisk sending a Contact-Header Contact: <sip:172.17.0.2:5060> along with its messages, is this correct?
How can I make asterisk use the proper external IP 1.2.3.4 - address instead of its local IP?
I mean, it also uses the proper external IP in negotiating the media endpoints?
Thanks a lot in advance!
